# Show that the limit of two sequences is equal.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a seq. $(f_n)_n \subset E \subset L^p$ $1 \leq p < \infty$ which converges to $f \in L^p$ and the inclusion operator $i: L^p \to L^{\infty}$. I wanna prove that 
the limit of the seq. $i(f_n) = f$. I thought I could do the following.

Denote the limit of $i(f_n) = g \in L^{\infty}$. But $i(f_n) = f_n$. And we already know that $f_n \to f$, and the limit is unique. Thus $g=f$. But looking at in the solution manual, the started to talk about subseq. and I dont understand why.

The question arrised when I was asked to prove that the inclusion operator from $L^p \to L^{\infty}$ is cont.

> Let $L^p = L^p([0,1],dt)$ where $dt$ denotes the Lebesgue measure in the unit interval. Suppose $E\subset L^p, \ 1\leq p < \infty$ is a closed linear subspace with $E\subset L^{\infty}$

Comment: In what measure space are you working? The inclusion $L^p\subset L^\infty$ does not hold in general.

Comment: I have updated the question with the information I unintentionally left out. @JuliánAguirre